# GWT groupabled Rows in celltable or in datagrid

Tags: gwt2

I beginn to learn GWT,  now need  celltable groupable. just like in OUT Look, for example, die E-mails can be accroding to the date grouped.(today,yersterday,or this week...) one kann expand or close the rows. and dynamic sorted!

Somebody can help me? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Check this link
[Link](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid)

GWT showcase example. try to customise with GROUPING, EXPAND/COLLAPSE, SORTING features.

If hav any queries post with sample code.